# 404 css and js not found, wrong [civicrm.root]

Tags: joomla, installation, civicrm.settings.php, css

a fresh install on Joomla 3.6.4 with CiviCRM 4.7.13 results in countless 404 errors

All files of those locations are not found:

- css
- bower_components
- packages
- js

It tries to find the files from those folders in the wrong location:
/home/...serverinfo.../www/...website.../components/com_civicrm/civicrm

but the correct location would be:
/home/...serverinfo.../www/...website.../**administrator**/components/com_civicrm/civicrm

The variable: [civicrm.root] is set correctly including the **administrator** folder

The civicrm.settings.php is defined like this:
$civicrm_root = '/home/...serverinfo.../www/...website.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/';

Please, is there anywhere else where I can look for a wrong configuration of the [civicrm.root]?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the web resources in the screen *Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs* (That is different from file locations).

In this screen, you can set the resource URL (see (1)) as complete URL, as the relative path and with the use of URL variables. So you can avoid using the using `[civicrm.root]`. And it has another neat feature. If you ask help by clicking the question mark, the values of the URL variables are displayed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding the complete URL works now!
Still I would like to know whey the variable [civicrm.root] does not work here.
When I click on the question mark, the value of it show the correct URL!
But it does now work using the variable
Any idea why?

Comment: Marc I have a patch in the works which may fix this problem for Joomla. If you could give it a try on your site that would be extremely helpful! Try changing the paths back to use `[civicrm_root]`, verify the problem persists and then apply [this patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9458.diff) to see if it fixes the issue. Please leave a comment on the [pull-request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9458) to let us know how it works.